# Are these convex cones polyhedral?

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, cones

I'm actually playing with some convex cones, and I would like to know if there is a chance they would be described by a finite number of inequalities.

Let me introduce some notation first.

Let $n\geq 2$ be an integer, let $\mathcal{G}$ be a family of **finite** groups. I denote by $[n]$ the set of nonempty subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For any $G\in\mathcal{G}$,  any subgroups $G_1,\ldots,G_n$ and any $\alpha\in [n]$, set $G_\alpha=\bigcap_{i\in\alpha}G_i.$

I will denote by $\gamma_n(\mathcal{G})\subset \mathbb{R}^{2^n-1}$ the set of conic combinations (i.e. the set of  linear combinations with non negative real coefficients) of the vectors of the form $$(\log_2([G:G_\alpha]))_{\alpha\in [n]},$$
where $G\in \mathcal{G}$ and $G_1,\ldots,G_n$ are subgroups of $G.$

Before asking my questions, let me make few side remarks:

1) General theory of convex cones says that it is enough to consider conic combinations with at most $2^n-1$ terms.

2) For each conic combination, one can easily show that we can take the same $G$ for all the vectors involved in the combination.

Now for the questions:

**Question 1.** Let $p$ be a given prime number. If $\mathcal{G}$ is the family of finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$ -vector spaces, is $\gamma_n(\mathcal{G})$ polyhedral (i.e. described by a finite number of inequalities) ?

I'm pretty sure that the answer to this question is known, but I could not find any reference.

I know for sure it is true for $n\leq 4.$

**Question 2.** Same as question 1., but taking this time the family of finite abelian $p$-groups.

Thanks in advance for any information/answer you could provide.

Cheers,

Greg